# Unable to Rectify the Error?

Tags: php, html

I programming a cash denomination sheet using PHP and HTML,Below you can see my both html code and PHP code, i am unable to execute in the xampp severer and facing with these errors.I am Unable to Rectify the error.

Notice: Undefined index: L in C:\xampp\htdocs\cashdenomination.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: D in C:\xampp\htdocs\cashdenomination.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: E1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cashdenomination.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: E2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cashdenomination.php on line 6

Here is my HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table
        {
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
        }
        th
        {
            background-color: aqua;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
<form action="cashdenomination.php" method="post">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">KLCP HEALTHY FOODS PRIVTE LIMITED</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">CASH DENOMMINATION</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DATE</td>
            <td><input name="date" type="date" size="5"></td>
            <td>LOCATION</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><b>SALE PROCEEDS</b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b>EXPENSES</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lunch</td>
            <td><input name="L"type="text" value="<?php echo @$l;?>" size="15"></td>
            <td>Expenses 1</td>
            <td><input name="E1"type="text" value="<?php echo @$exp1;?>" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dinner</td>
            <td><input name="D" type="text" value="<?php echo @$d;?>" size="15"></td>
            <td>Expenses 2</td>
            <td><input name="E2" type="text" value="<?php echo @$exp2;?>" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>TOTAL SALE</b></td>
            <td><input name="TS" type="text" value="<?php echo @$sum;?>" size="15"></td>
            <td><b>TOTAL EXPENSE</b></td>
            <td><input name="TE"type="text" value="<?php echo @$expsum;?>" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><b>PAYMENT TYPE</b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b>DENOMINATIONS</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL CASH</td>
            <td><input name="TC" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td>NET CASH</td>
            <td><input name="NC" type="text" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sodexo</td>
            <td><input name="Sodexo" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td>2000</td>
            <td><input name="TT" type="text" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>EDC</td>
            <td><input name="EDC" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td>500</td>
            <td><input name="FH" type="text" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>Paytm</td>
            <td><input name="PT" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td><input name="OH" type="text" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>M.Card</td>
            <td><input name="MealCard" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td><input name="FT" type="text" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input name="v1" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td><input name="v2" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td><input name="TW"type="text" size="15"></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><input name="v3" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td><input name="v4" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td><input name="T" type="text" size="15"></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><input name="v5" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td><input name="v6" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td>Coins</td>
            <td><input name="coins" type="text" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td>
            <td><input name="Total" type="text" size="15"></td>
            <td>NET CASH</td>
            <td><input name="Netcash" type="text" size="15"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Done By</td>
            <td colspan="3"><input name="doneby" type="text" size="35"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <center>
        <input type="submit" name="add" >
    </center> 
    </form>
</body>
```

And Here is My PHP code

```
<?php

$l=$_POST['L'];
$d=$_POST['D'];
$exp1=$_POST['E1'];
$exp2=$_POST['E2'];
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $sum=$l+$d;
    $expsum=$exp1+$exp2;
    header("Location:CashDenomination.php");

}
```

?>

Comment: @Bhanu Banda  `Undefined index:` means you need to define the variable your. But here it is dynamically defining so you can ignore this error by `@$l=$_POST['L'];` this will not so the error.

Comment: THank you Pavan Baddi, Its has rectified my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$l=$_POST['L'];
$d=$_POST['D'];
$exp1=$_POST['E1'];
$exp2=$_POST['E2'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $sum=$l+$d;
    $expsum=$exp1+$exp2;
    header("Location:CashDenomination.php");

}
```

change  **$_POST['add']**  to **$_POST['submit']**

**Tested**

Comment: Thanks  for the edit @HimeshSuthar,

Comment: if it helped you.. i would appreciate if you can mark it as correct @BhanuBanda

Comment: header("Location:CashDenomination.php") is traversing the page ,But the page is Blank. Can you help me with that ??

Comment: yes. its same php. you haven't echo any thing so its blank with no error...@BhanuBanda